# How to mark seams on a low poly UV sphere with the poles extruded. Dont know how to make UV look nice

Tags: uv

I am making a low poly ship wheel that has bulbous parts in the handle. I was making the UV and I noticed that the UV sphere part was not working well. I marked seams at the top and bottom of the sphere and the sides but there was still distortion [image: bisect sphere]

Then I tried cutting the sphere into slices like an orange and that gave better results

[image]

The issue with this method is that the texture will be very chopped up in substance painter. This is how the UV looks
[image]

So is there a way to link the UV islands better or different seam placement?

Comment: What does it give if you choose the front view and unwrap with the Cylinder Projection option? Or mark a vertical seam, unwrap and use the To Grid by Shape button of the UV Squares addon to make the UV square. You'll need to scale the UV though

Comment: The cylinder projection UV made me feel a bit ill. the poor checker texture was completely abused. I will look into this UV squares addon

Comment: You need to be in front and orthographic view when you choose Cylinder Projection, or tweak the parameters in the Operator Box

Comment: yes I was in front view

Comment: In the UV Squares addon try also the To Square Grid option. That said you'll always have some stretching problem that you'll need to fix afterwards

Comment: There's also the Follow Active Quad unwrap option, just make a square face of your object active so that it creates a perpendicular UV

Comment: I dont want to buy an addon for this problem. $15 is steep for me

Comment: It's free on github: https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares but you can use the Follow Active Quads method, it will give about the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146285/discussion-between-stonedsasquatch-and-moonboots).

Comment: I tried it but theres not one quad thats even

Comment: Yes there are, on the top or bottom tube, and anyway you can make it one quad in the UV Editor

Comment: If my answer is not correct, please explain precisely why

Answer (score 0):

Select your whole mesh in *Edit* mode, shift select a face that is square, press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Follow Active Quads*, it will align the UV on the selected face, if it's square the whole UV will be perpendicular:

[image]

Result in the *UV Editor*:

[image]

How the texture is projected on the surface:

[image]